# Write ISO on DVD in Ubuntu 16.04 Live USB (non-persistent)

Tags: 16.04, system-installation, live-usb, windows-10, iso

I have a non-persistent Live USB of Ubuntu 16.04. I want write an ISO file (windows 10 download from Microsoft website) on a DVD. I don't have access to other computers to create a persistent LIVE USB or other versions or Ubuntu. As you know, Ubuntu 16.04 doesn't have DVD writer app and we can't install apps in Live USB. What is your solution for this problem? As mentioned, I don't have access to other computers and resources. I only have an ISO file and Ubuntu without installation (non-persistent).

Comment: You should still be able to install a burning application like `brasero` as long as the computer booted to the Live still has internet access.  The application just will not be saved once you reboot.

Comment: if your LiveUSB is the same as the LiveCD, It is Loaded to a RAM drive. Thus, you can install packages, but the change is not recorded to the USB so you would have to install everytime you boot.

Comment: @Terrance  Suppose that I want install brasero in terminal. It returns this error:  "E: Package 'brasero' has no installation candidate"

Comment: @ravery I receive this error when I want install every app.

Comment: do you have internet access? and the repositories set?

Comment: @ravery Yes. I have INTERNET access and I inserted "sudo apt-get update" before that. Is it enough? I didn't have this problem when I had installed Ubuntu on Hard-Drive.

Comment: check /etc/apt/sources.list to see if it points to an online repository.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With LiveCDs since they are not persistent, you can still make changes but only temporary ones.  LiveCDs do not come with repositories enabled by default so most applications cannot be installed.  However, you can add repositories for temporary usage.  Then you can install the applications.

From a terminal type in the following:

```
sudo bash -c 'echo "deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main multiverse restricted universe" >> /etc/apt/sources.list'
sudo bash -c 'echo "deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main multiverse restricted universe" >> /etc/apt/sources.list'
```

Then all you should have to do is the updates then install the application.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install brasero
```