# Ubuntu setup shows combined ntfs drive

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

I have Windows10 installed on my machine, and I want to setup Ubuntu as dual boot.

I have prepared bootable USB for Ubuntu 14.04, tried running Live CD, which works fine. When running installation, I don't see all my drives as they appear in Windows.

All the drives in Windows (First, Second, Third, Fourth, unallocated); they all appear as one `/dev/sda4`

How to fix this?

[This is how it appears in Disk Management tab on Windows 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJTPZ.jpg)

[Ubuntu drive selection screen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMRpD.jpg)

Comment: Your Windows partitions were converted to Dynamic and the Ubuntu tools do not know how to handle it.  You can try installing `ldmtool` http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man1/ldmtool.1.html  as it might be the only way to view the drive as it is laid out.

Comment: That's a Windows [dynamic disk](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363785(v=vs.85).aspx). On a dynamic disk volumes do not have to correspond to partitions, and, in this specific case, they actually do not. Linux does not understand Windows dynamic disks; I would strongly suggest that you do not attempt to use a Windows dynamic disk with Linux.

Comment: @Terrance - How can I use `ldmtool` while I don't have ubuntu installed yet.

@AlexP - Is there a way to make non-dynamic partitions? So that Ubuntu can pickup?

Comment: Boot into the Try Ubuntu, then follow this:  https://askubuntu.com/a/972548/231142  But replace Brasero with `ldmtool`.  It is not persistent, but you can use it temporarily.